# Regexp UTF-8 with ASCII-8BIT string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, encoding

I am generating rails' select tags with dynamic values like this:

```
<% @locsprelist = [] %>
<% @locationsprelist.each do |t| %>
    <% @locsprelist.push(Base64.decode64(t[:short_name]), t[:serno]) %>
<% end %>
```

and then:

```
select_tag(:quicksearch, options_for_select(@locsprelist))
```

When I get locations with names in English alphabet, everything is OK, but when there is a location name from another language (for example Georgian: `თბილისი`), I get an error "incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8  regexp with ASCII-8BIT string)".

When I try to put down those words like:

```
<% @locationsprelist.each do |t| %>
  <%= Base64.decode64(t[:short_name]) %>
<% end %>
```

it works fine even with foreign alphabet. The problem occurs when I try to push those words in an array.

Comment: It seems to me that your input string is using ASCII while your regex is using UTF-8 which means it will work for the Latin alphabet, but ASCII doesn't support non-Latin letters (such as Georgian or certain accents). I don't think your input string should be able to even display `თბილისი`

Comment: I made an update to my post, please have a look again.

Comment: Are you sure that `Base64.decode64` can take two strings parameters?

Comment: No I decode only one string each time.

Comment: exact, I haven't seen the closing parenthese

Comment: What returns `Base64.decode64(t[:short_name]).encoding`?

Comment: only ASCII-8BIT, on each of them.

Comment: try to use `Base64.decode64(t[:short_name]).force_encoding 'utf-8'`.

Comment: I have tried it, even tried with `Base64.decode64(r[:short_name].encode('utf-8', 'binary', :invalid => :replace, 
  :undef => :replace, :replace => '')`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you show us the base64 representation of the problematic string?

Comment: 4YOX4YOR4YOY4YOa4YOY4YOh4YOY this is it in base64.
when I push it(decoded) into array it puts out "\xE1\x83\x97\xE1\x83\x91\xE1\x83\x98\xE1\x83\x9A\xE1\x83\x98\xE1\x83\xA1\xE1\x83\x98"